# libsasl2.so.2 error on installing MYSQL on Amazon EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have installed PHP7.2 and now installing MySQL 5.7 on Amazon's instance.

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
yum install mysql-community-server
```

getting this error on Amazon EC2:

```
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.24-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libsasl2.so.2()(64bit)
```

How can I resolve this dependency? and would there be any issues if I switch to MariaDB in terms of performance (as it's already a wrapper on MySQL)?